# Problem updating Java on Mac minecraft server

Tags: java, macos, server, minecraft

I am having trouble getting Minecraft 18.0 to run on my Mac server.  When I try to start the server I get the error message shown below.

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.minecraft.bundler.Main java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0
```

I was getting that same error when I had Java 8u311 installed.

My problem is that I have downloaded and installed jdk-17.0.1 as suggested in another post here and I am still getting this error. I tried powering down and doing a restart of the server computer after installing Java 17 to make sure there were no leftover parts or pieces the might interfere.  But I still get that error.

Comment: I don't know anything about Mac but are you sure minecraft is using the jdk-17.0.1 and not still just the old version? For starters if Mac has a command prompt if you type java -version what does that say?

Comment: You're still using Java 16 (see [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2) in the Java Language Specification for class version numbers).  How are you launching Minecraft?  It could be that a script is still pointing to Java 16.  In a console execute `java -version` to find out what's on the path and `which java` to find out where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Such as the error said, the given jar is compiled with an highest Java version. It require Java 17.

If you download it but it's not applied, try using `java -version` in your cmd, and you will see which version is selected.

If it's not the good one (which seems to be your issue) :

- Check the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` & `JRE_HOME` value to refer to Java 17 and not Java 8.
- Close all Java instance (Minecraft client ...)
- Restart your computer to apply everything

Finally, the version should be bumped to 17 and not stay at Java 8.